# Connect kernel image (bzImage) running on qemu to network

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a kernel 3.2.0 bzImage compiled which I am running on a qemu  emulator, now I want to download linux headers to the kernel image so I can compile modules within it but I am unable to connect to the internet. The `ifconfig` command returns the following output:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:640 (640.0 B)  TX bytes:640 (640.0 B)
```

The `eth0` and `wlan0` are not showing up at all, can anyone help me with the same ? My host machine is connect via wireless interface to the network so I guess that is what I would need working for qemu as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these options to your qemu command:

`-netdev type=user,id=net0
 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac="52:54:00:12:34:56"`

If it doesn't work take a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking.

Also, it might be interesting to look at tap interfaces and bridges.